# Increasing thread and process priority to reduce execution time for a processor-intensive, parallelized application

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, performance, optimization

I know that setting thread priority is a bit of a taboo subject on stack overflow but I am convinced that my application is a good candidate for increased priority. To justify that, I have explained the context below. The question now is HOW to do that effectively?

The application is .NET 4 (C#) console application that executes a complex algorithm with an execution time of about five hours. The algorithm is not memory-intensive at all, just processor intensive. It does number crunching and does NOT perform any disk I/O, database connectivity, network connectivity, etc. The output of the application is a just ONE number that it writes to the console at the end. In other words, the algorithm is completely self-contained and has no dependencies.

The application runs on its own dedicated 16 core 64 bit machine running Windows Server with far more free RAM than it requires (8GB). By dedicated I mean the server has been procured to run this application EXCLUSIVELY.

I have already optimized the code as much as I could with extensive profiling, fancy math shortcuts and bit twiddling hacks.

Here is the overall structure in pseudocode:

```
public static void Main ()
{
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityBoostEnabled = true;
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.RealTime;

    // Of course this only affects the main thread rather than child threads.
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;

    BigInteger seed = SomeExtremelyLargeNumber; // Millions of digits.

    // The following loop takes [seed] and processes some numbers.
    result1 = Parallel.For(/* With thread-static variables. */);

    while (true) // Main loop that cannot be parallelized.
    {
        // Processes result1.
        result2 = Parallel.For(/* With thread-static variables. */);

        // Processes result2.
        result1 = Parallel.For(/* With thread-static variables. */);

        if (result1 == criteria)
            break;

        // Note: This loop does not need to sleep or care about system responsiveness.
    }
}
```

Now based on the thread priority related questions on SO, I gather that anything using ThreadPool should not be messed around with in terms of priority. So If I need to switch to manual threads, so be it.

**Question:**

- How should I change the above code to manual threading to benefit from increased thread priority (not using thread pool etc.)?
- Will setting priority to highest on all child threads even help? I mean will the child threads just be fighting with each other or will that give them an edge over external OS tasks?
- Considering there are 16 cores, should I be running 16 or 15 threads? Is there a general guideline to this?
- Will setting process priority to real-time help as well?

Comment: As a sideinterest of me, I have a library of bit twiddling stuff which is going to be on sourceforge soon. I can email you the routines for uint or ulong if you want.

Comment: I know it is 5 years later, but if you are still working on this project you might want to look into C++ AMP to take advantage of the GPU processing power. GPUs are great at doing parallel work. It's a somewhat steep learning curve but done right it may execute code much faster. You may also want to read about CUDA and OpenCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With such an app, I would expect changing the priorities to make 0% difference to the overall runtime.  If you're already maxed out on CPU use with all 16 cores at 100% doing real work, there's not much more you can do.

Comment: Then I guess setting process-level priority to real-time should take care of it all? And by the way do you mean to say that I should continue to use TPL or switch to manual threads?

Comment: I would only change your design if the threadpool was not peforming as well as you would expect.  If the Task Manager shows all cores at 100%, that's it.  Changing the process priority to real-time won't make much difference either, though if you can raise the priority of the process/threads enough, you may be able to sieze up the machine completely until you app is done, ie. prevent even the Task Manager from getting any CPU.  Lowering the process priority won't make any difference either.  Try it and see!

Comment: Sounds about right. Sad to realize that nothing will drastically reduce execution times in a dedicated scenario.

Comment: If you are using a web browser, M$ Office Word etc, it won't make much difference to overall run time either.  Those other apps will use 0.1% of the available CPU and your app will soak up the other 99.9%.

Comment: I agree completely. Thread and process priorities are more about time constraints than load optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bother with setting the priority for individual threads, just do it for the entire process, since most of its threads are doing important work apparently.

**However**, I don't expect it to make any difference for CPU intensive apps like yours. The only processes that could forcibly preempt your own process are I/O intensive apps that traditionally are favored by most OSes, but since you have a dedicated machine, that won't be a problem (also, Windows Server is pretty lightweight in my experience, so it won't interfere if your app is the only one running).

As a side-note:

> The algorithm is not memory-intensive at all, just processor
>   intensive. It does number crunching and does NOT perform any disk I/O,
>   database connectivity, network connectivity, etc.

The fact that it does not perform "obvious" I/O operations does not mean that it cannot be memory intensive. If you are processing large arrays or other data-structures, the CPU will constantly emit read/write operations to the main memory and a lot of work is being done to move data between the various memory levels. Even working with just numbers can negatively impact the performance of a program if done incorrectly.

Comment: Well, based on the logic I have, there will be at most 200 BigInteger objects at one time in memory taking up not more than 100MB. There are other objects floating around.

Comment: @Raheel Khan: It was just an observation I was making. I don't know if it applies to your code or not, but it can happen in general.

Answer (score 1):

My code can change the priority of the process and the threads.

```
public void SetPriorityProcessAndTheards(string nameProcess,ProcessPriorityClass processPriority, ThreadPriorityLevel threadPriorityLevel)
{
    foreach(Process a in Process.GetProcessesByName(nameProcess))
    {
        a.PriorityBoostEnabled = true;
        a.PriorityClass = processPriority;

        foreach(ProcessThread processThread in a.Threads)
        {
            processThread.PriorityLevel = threadPriorityLevel;
            processThread.PriorityBoostEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you to limit the number of threads to the number of cores/threads. Sometimes the Parallel Task Library uses too many threads. For your cpumaxed process either corecount or threadcount (hyperthreading fakecores added) would be best, so supply and fix the threadcount;

```
 // Create a ParallelOptions object and supply this to the Parallel.For() 

 var po = new ParallelOptions {MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount}
 Parallel.For(,,po,);

 // Environment.ProcessorCount gives number of Cores (NOT processors)
 // Never found out how to detect fake cores or hyperthreads, check Task Monitor ;-)
```

You can re-use the po object for all the parallel.For() statements. I have never really benefitted from priority fiddling, even on CPU bound threaded apps.

Comment: I'm already using Environment.ProcessorCount to get all cores working. I have not figured out how to get fake cores as well but I doubt that running 1 thread per fake core will benefit. It may make it worse actually.